# Remove services from context menus (but leave them in the app's Services menu)

Tags: finder, automator, services, shortcut-menu

I created a few services with Automator and it seems OS X automatically adds these to the context menu of files/folders that they apply to. Is it possible to remove the services from the context menu BUT still have them be accessible from the application's Services menu (under App Name > Services)?

Services appear to be stored in ~/Library/Services, and when I remove them from this folder, they're removed from both the context menu and the Services menu.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try [Services Manager.app](http://www.macosxautomation.com/services/servicesmanager/):

[image]

Download the application and put it into your /Applications folder (or any other convenient place). After you started it you can configure each service to appear in the Services menu (by enabling it in the Active column), in the Context Menu (by enabling it in the Context Menu) or in both.

Comment: How does this do that? The front page does not seem to say anything about context menus. You should provide the answer here not just a link :)

Comment: "I was young and needed the money" :-) OTOH it is kind of self-explaining, but I get your point.